# Is a Child Process executed immediately, or in a future iteration of the event loop?

Tags: node.js

Does process_child.spawn() start the process immediately, or does it wait until the current execution context clears the stack?

The [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_asynchronous_process_creation) say that "spawn ... follows the idiomatic asynchronous programming pattern typical of other Node.js APIs."

Does that imply that process execution is deferred as a callback queue event, to be picked up by the event loop after the spawn() caller's execution context clears the stack?

My concern is that the spawned process could trigger events (eg, write to stdout) before my code has had a chance to install a handler for them.  And it seems I'm not the only one with this concern: https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/4030#issuecomment-315392492

Comment: We could probably help you more completely if you told us why you want to know this and how it affects your programming or your code.

Comment: @jfriend00 I added why I want to know and how it affects my programming.  Thanks for all the feedback!

Comment: Missing stdio events is not an issue as long as you install your event handlers in the same tick as you call `spawn()` (e.g. not in some async callback),  As I think my answer explains, all stdio data comes via the event queue and thus won't arrive until a future tick of the event loop so as long as you install both your error handling and any listeners you want in the same tick as you called `spawn()`, you won't miss them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The docs say that "spawn ... follows the idiomatic asynchronous programming pattern typical of other Node.js APIs."
>
> Does that imply that process execution is deferred as a callback queue event, to be picked up by the event loop after the spawn() caller's execution context clears the stack?

No.  It does not imply that.  The idiomatic asynchronous programming pattern is to initiate the asynchronous operation in the current tick and then once it is started and being executed or controlled by other means, then control is returned back to Javascript.  Future events will communicate its status or result at that point.  The same is true of other typical asynchronous operation such as file I/O or network I/O.

As with most async APIs, it calls the OS synchronously to tell it to launch the other app and then exactly how much work towards actually starting the other process gets done before it returns control back to your JS depends upon the OS and internals of the implementation on a specific OS. To know more specifically exactly what it waits for before returning, you'd have to examine the native code source code for your particular platform and then you'd have to delve into what the OS calls that it's using do on your platform.

The general model is that the asynchronous operation is initiated and then it returns control back to your JS. Since what is going on in this async operation is the launching of a new process and the OS takes care of the real work in another process, there wouldn't be any reason for node.js to postpone actually calling the OS until a future tick of the event loop. You can't get any events from the the new process until a future tick of the event loop anyway because those events all go through the event queue.

Working through the node.js source code, it gets to [here in the source code](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/src/process_wrap.cc#L258) where it calls `uv_spawn()` in libuv (the cross platform library node.js is built on). It looks to me like everything has been synchronous up to this point (no waiting for next tick). Next step is to look into libuv code to see what `uv_spawn()` does.

It is interesting to note when following the source code that exceptions or synchronous errors are caught internally and emitted as events on future ticks (not synchronously). This allows you to get the child_process object returned from the function back from the `spawn()` call, install event handlers on it and not miss any events.

`uv_spawn()` source code is [here](https://github.com/libuv/libuv/blob/619937c783a05b51fba95cc9a62543deeffe5fa7/src/unix/process.c#L411) and it appears to make an OS call to `fork()` on the same tick.

### TLDR

So, I see no evidence of any purposeful postponing the actual OS call to start the new process to a future tick.  It appears to call the OS on the same tick.  There is evidence of postponing error reporting to a future tick to simplify use of the interface.

To your additional point you added, the streams that receive stdio and stdout are set up before the new process is started.  Since they will receive data from the new process via the JS event queue, as long as you set up your own event handlers on those streams in the same tick that you call `spawn()` (e.g. not in some async callback), then those event handlers will be installed before any data can be received and notified on the stdio and stdout streams.  This is a product of the single-threaded, event driven nature of node.js Javascript.